# Age word problem

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

Adam is now one quarter of his father's age and in $5$ years time, his age will be one-third the age of his father. How old is Adam now?

I have trouble with these kind of questions and I've spent half an hour trying to figure it out but I still don't know how to get the answer D:

Comment: How did you approach it? Can you show your thoughts in that half hour, and what exactly it is that is giving you trouble?

Comment: Try to designate ages as certain variables then "translate" these words into equations to solve

Comment: This is not a linear algebra question!

Answer (score 6):

Let $x$ be Adam's current age, and let $y$ be his father's current age. The statement

> Adam is now one quarter of his father's age

means $$x=\frac{1}{4}y,$$ and the statement

> in 5 years time, his age will be one third the age of his father

means $$(x+5)=\frac{1}{3}(y+5),$$ because in $5$ years, Adam's age will be $x+5$, and his father's age will be $y+5$.

So, you have the system of equations
$$\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{1}{4}y\\\\\\\\
(x+5)&=\frac{1}{3}(y+5)
\end{align*}$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\begin{align*}
4x&=y\\\\\\\
3x+15&=y+5
\end{align*}$$
and then further rewritten as
$$\begin{align*}
4x-y&=0\\\\\\\
3x-y&=-10
\end{align*}$$
Do you know how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let Adam's current age be $x$ years so that the current age of his father is $4x$ years

According to the given condition $x+5=\frac{4x+5}3\implies 4x+5=3x+15\implies x=10$